# OWS + Jdk17 - Denying permission (java.policy issue?)

Tags: java, java-17, openwebstart

We're using Open Web Start with java 17 (OWS 1.8 with Java Ecplipse Adoptium 17.0.7). We get a lot of 'Denying permission:' Messages. Example :

```
Denying permission: ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.0.244" "resolve")
Denying permission: ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.0.244" "resolve")
Denying permission: ("java.net.SocketPermission" "192.168.0.244" "resolve")
Denying permission: ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
Denying permission: ("java.net.SocketPermission" "vm2022v7st:49835" "connect,resolve")
Denying permission: ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "showWindowWithoutWarningBanner")
```

I tried to set up a java.policy with All Permissions, but without success.

```
grant {
    // Allow everything for now
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Any ideas why this file is not taken in account? I attached the console log showing that the file is read.

[Edit] Additionnal info : We identified that the problem seems to be linked with JavaFx. Everything else works fine, but as soon as javafx gets involved, we get permission errors.

Also, when specifying '--nosecurity' in command line (javaws --nosecurity ourApp.jnlp), everything works fine.
=> This solution would be okay if we could force this parameter within the jnlp (or some other way than via command line). Is this possible?

Thanks a lot !